# Prove that particular set in $l^2$ is open in weak topology

Tags: general-topology, weak-convergence

I have a set $M$ in $l^2$: $$M= \{x = (x_1, x_2, ...) \in l_2:|x_n|<\sqrt[3]n 
~~~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$ 
The goal is to prove that this set is NOT open in weak topology. I tried to use this criteria: $U$ is open in weak topology if $\forall x \in U~$ $\exists f_1,f_2 \dots,f_n \in X^* , n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0$

$$V_x:=\{y \in X:|f_j(x)-f_j(y)|< \epsilon ~~\forall j=1 \dots n \} \subseteq U$$

But I'm stuck. Is there any other way to prove that a set is not open?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $M$ weak-open. Since $0\in M$, there exists $f_{1},...,f_{n}$ such that
$$ V:=\left\{y\in l^{2}:|f_{j}(y)|<1\ \forall j\in\{1,...,n\}\right\}\subseteq M $$
Let $f\in(l^{2})^{*}=l^{2}$ bounded in $V$ and $x\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\ker(f_{i})$. If $f(x)\not=0$, then, since $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\ker(f_{i})\subseteq V$ is a subspace, $f$ is not be bounded in $V$ (just take $tx$ and let $t\to\infty$). So, $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\ker(f_{i})\subseteq\ker(f)$ and therefore $f\in \operatorname{span} \{f_1,...,f_n\}$. We conclude that some $e_{n}=(0,...,1,...)$ is not bounded in $V$ and thus $V\not\subseteq M$ (note that $e_{n}((x_1,..))=x_{n}$).

Comment: what do you mean by "bounded in $V$"?

Comment: $f(V)$ bounded in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: So, we proved that if $f$ is bounded in $V$ it should $\in span\{f_1,...,f_n\}$. But there exist some $e_n$ (as functional) that is $\notin span\{f_1,...,f_n\}$. Hence, it's not bounded in $V$, but actually every $e_n$ is bounded in $V$. 
But I don't quite understand why if $f(x)\not=0$, then $f$ is not be bounded in $V$. Could you please explain it more?

Comment: 1. If $f(x)\not=0$, then $|f(tx)|=|t||f(x)|\to_{t\to\infty}\infty$. We deduce that $f$ is not bounded in $V$(because $tx\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\ker(f_i)\subseteq V$). So, $f(x)$ must be zero.
$$.$$
2.If $M$ is weak-open, then we can find $V$. Since $\{e_{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is linearly independet, some $e_{k}$ is not in $span\{f_{1},...,f_k\}$ and, in this way, it is not bounded in $V$, and therefore in $M$. The contradiction arises from the asumption _$M$ is weak-open_.

Comment: 1. I don't understand your defenition of bounded functional. $f$ is bounded if there is constant $M>0$ such as $|f(x)| \le M||x||$. Why $f(tx)$?

Comment: In 1. I proved that $f(V)$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$. So, I said "$f$ is bounded **on $V$**".